# Captions above figures w/ KOMA-Script -- captions=heading seems to be ignored

Tags: floats, captions, koma-script, scrartcl

I would like to have figure captions appear above the figures themselves. The KOMA-Script documentation seems to suggest this can be achieved by setting the `captions=heading` option. But in the MWE below, the first caption always appears below, and the second above the image.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[captions=heading]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{image}
  \caption{First caption (caption command below the figure)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Second caption (caption command above the figure)}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Just move the caption above the `\includegraphics`-command

Comment: I should have added that this is not possible, since the latex source is generated automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [KOMA-script manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) page 128, this behaviour is documented:

> Note that these options change only the formatting, not the actual position of the caption. Whether the caption is placed above or below a float depends solely upon where you use the \caption command inside float environment. However, this can change when using the float package with the \restylefloats command (see [Lin01]).

To have a float (as you have) be typeset with the caption above the figure, you need to place the caption inside the float, but above the line that inputs the figure. `caption=heading` provides the formatting, *i.e*. that you have sufficient space below the caption.

When this is not possible, you may try not to use floats, and use

```
\captionaboveof{float type}[entry]{title}
```

See the KOMA-manual page 132, or you can try the [float](https://ctan.org/pkg/float)-package and its `\restylefloat` command.

```
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{figure}
```

If you prefer KOMA-features (and you probably are), use

```
\floatstyle{komaabove}
\restylefloat{figure}
```

When using this commands (and scrhack) the usual KOMA-script commands for font attributes, spacing etc. works, and all the figures end up in list of figure, if you have such listing in your document. Complete MWE (loads `scrhack` as recommended in the manual:

[image]

```
\documentclass[captions=heading]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float, scrhack}  : KOMA-manual page 128 

\floatstyle{komaabove}
\restylefloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{image}
  \caption{First caption (caption command below the figure)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Second caption (caption command above the figure)}
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```